# Htaccess permanent redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I'm trying to perform the following single redirect:

```
http://www.mapfre.com.gt/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=37%3Acontactenos-ventas&catid=3%3Aproductos&Itemid=15
```

301 redirect to:

```
https://www.mapfre.com.gt/seguros-gt/sobre-mapfre-guatemala/contacto/
```

I've been researching this and have tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=37%3Acontactenos-ventas&catid=3%3Aproductos&Itemid=15$

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.mapfre.com.gt/seguros-gt/sobre-mapfre-guatemala/contacto/ [R=301,L]
```

But this results in:

```
https://www.mapfre.com.gt/seguros-gt/sobre-mapfre-guatemala/contacto/?option=com_content&view=article&id=37%253Acontactenos-ventas&catid=3%253Aproductos&Itemid=15
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `?` to the rewrite to truncate the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=37%3Acontactenos-ventas&catid=3%3Aproductos&Itemid=15$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.mapfre.com.gt/seguros-gt/sobre-mapfre-guatemala/contacto/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now works fine. It was an insignificant detail, but I was desperate.